# HDMI works in safe mode, but not much else

Tags: raspbian, hdmi

I have my board plugged into my monitor as an HDMI input. I can get to the Raspbian desktop by uncommenting the "hdmi_safe=1" in config.txt. However, I'd like to work in a resolution that doesn't make my eye's bleed, so I've been trying for the last couple days to find the correct settings in the config.txt, and I've about given up. Any help would be great. I've tried several modes, but no matter what I try I get no image and the following from tvservice -s:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -s
state: HPD low|HDMI off|NTSC mode|composite CP off (0x140001), 720x480 @ 60Hz, interlaced
```

What steps do I need to take to work through this problem? Thanks in advanced. The monitor in question is a Acer H243HX.

Here is my results for CEA testing:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -m CEA
Group CEA has 0 modes:
```

Here is my results for DMT testing:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -m DMT
Group DMT has 0 modes:
```

Here is my edid parser output:

```
Parsing edid.dat...

HDMI:EDID version 1.3, 1 extensions, screen size 53x29 cm

HDMI:EDID features - videodef 0x80 standby suspend active off; colour  encoding:RGB444|YCbCr422; sRGB is not default colourspace; preferred format is native; does not support GTF

HDMI:EDID found monitor name descriptor tag 0xfc

HDMI:EDID monitor name is H243H

HDMI:EDID found monitor range descriptor tag 0xfd

HDMI:EDID monitor range offsets: V min=0, V max=0, H min=0, H max=0

HDMI:EDID monitor range: vertical is 56-76 Hz, horizontal is 31-83 kHz, max pixel clock is 180 MHz

HDMI:EDID monitor range does not support GTF

HDMI:EDID found monitor S/N descriptor tag 0xff

HDMI:EDID found unknown detail timing format: 1920x1080p hfp:48 hs:32 hbp:80 vfp:3 vs:5 vbp:23 pixel clock:138 MHz

HDMI:EDID established timing I/II bytes are AF CF 00

HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 4, 640x480p @ 60 Hz in established timing I/II


HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 5, 640x480p @ 72 Hz in established timing I/II

HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 6, 640x480p @ 75 Hz in established timing I/II

HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 8, 800x600p @ 56 Hz in established timing I/II

HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 9, 800x600p @ 60 Hz in established timing I/II

HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 10, 800x600p @ 72 Hz in established timing I/II

HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 11, 800x600p @ 75 Hz in established timing I/II

HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 16, 1024x768p @ 60 Hz in established timing I/II

HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 17, 1024x768p @ 70 Hz in established timing I/II

HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 18, 1024x768p @ 75 Hz in established timing I/II

HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 36, 1280x1024p @ 75 Hz in established timing I/II

HDMI:EDID standard timings block x 8: 0x8180 714F 9500 950F A940 B300 0101 0101

HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 35, 1280x1024p @ 60 Hz (5:4) in standard timing 0

HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 21, 1152x864p @ 75 Hz (4:3) in standard timing 1

HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 47, 1440x900p @ 60 Hz (16:10) in standard timing 2

HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 48, 1440x900p @ 75 Hz (16:10) in standard timing 3

HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 51, 1600x1200p @ 60 Hz (4:3) in standard timing 4

HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 58, 1680x1050p @ 60 Hz (16:10) in standard timing 5

HDMI:EDID parsing v3 CEA extension 0

HDMI:EDID monitor support - underscan IT formats:yes, basic audio:yes, yuv444:yes, yuv422:yes, #native DTD:2

HDMI:EDID found preferred CEA detail timing format: 720x480p @ 60 Hz (2)

HDMI:EDID found CEA detail timing format: 1280x720p @ 60 Hz (4)

HDMI:EDID found CEA detail timing format: 1920x1080i @ 60 Hz (5)

HDMI:EDID found CEA detail timing format: 1280x720p @ 50 Hz (19)

HDMI:EDID found CEA detail timing format: 1920x1080i @ 50 Hz (20)

HDMI:EDID found audio format 2 channels PCM, sample rate: 32|44|48|88|96|176|192 kHz, sample size: 16|20|24 bits

HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 1, 640x480p @ 60Hz

HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 2, 720x480p @ 60Hz

HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 3, 720x480p @ 60Hz

HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 4, 1280x720p @ 60Hz (native)

HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 5, 1920x1080i @ 60Hz

HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 6, 1440x480i @ 60Hz

HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 7, 1440x480i @ 60Hz

HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 16, 1920x1080p @ 60Hz

HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 17, 720x576p @ 50Hz

HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 18, 720x576p @ 50Hz

HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 21, 1440x576i @ 50Hz

HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 19, 1280x720p @ 50Hz (native)

HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 31, 1920x1080p @ 50Hz

HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 20, 1920x1080i @ 50Hz

HDMI:EDID found HDMI VSDB length 6

HDMI:EDID HDMI VSDB has physical address 1.0.0.0

HDMI:EDID HDMI VSDB supports AI:no, dual link DVI:no

HDMI:EDID HDMI VSDB deep colour support - 48-bit:no 36-bit:no 30-bit:yes DC_yuv444:no

HDMI:EDID HDMI VSDB has no latency information

HDMI:EDID filtering formats with pixel clock > 162 MHz or h. blanking
> 1023

HDMI:EDID best score mode is now CEA (1) 640x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 25 MHz (score 136864)

HDMI:EDID best score mode is now CEA (2) 720x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz (score 5162208)

HDMI:EDID CEA mode (3) 720x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz has a score of 141472

HDMI:EDID CEA mode (4) 1280x720p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 74 MHz has a score of 4765888

HDMI:EDID DMT mode (4) 640x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 25 MHz has a score of 18432

HDMI:EDID CEA mode (5) 1920x1080i @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 74 MHz has a score of 4348832

HDMI:EDID DMT mode (5) 640x480p @ 72 Hz with pixel clock 31 MHz has a score of 22118

HDMI:EDID CEA mode (6) 1440x480i @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz has a score of 120736

HDMI:EDID DMT mode (6) 640x480p @ 75 Hz with pixel clock 31 MHz has a score of 23040

HDMI:EDID CEA mode (7) 1440x480i @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz has a score of 120736

HDMI:EDID DMT mode (8) 800x600p @ 56 Hz with pixel clock 36 MHz has a score of 26880

HDMI:EDID DMT mode (9) 800x600p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 40 MHz has a score of 28800

HDMI:EDID DMT mode (10) 800x600p @ 72 Hz with pixel clock 50 MHz has a score of 34560

HDMI:EDID DMT mode (11) 800x600p @ 75 Hz with pixel clock 49 MHz has a score of 36000

HDMI:EDID CEA mode (16) 1920x1080p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 148 MHz has a score of 348832

HDMI:EDID DMT mode (16) 1024x768p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 65 MHz has a score of 47185

HDMI:EDID CEA mode (17) 720x576p @ 50 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz has a score of 141472

HDMI:EDID DMT mode (17) 1024x768p @ 70 Hz with pixel clock 75 MHz has a score of 55050

HDMI:EDID CEA mode (18) 720x576p @ 50 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz has a score of 141472

HDMI:EDID DMT mode (18) 1024x768p @ 75 Hz with pixel clock 78 MHz has a score of 58982

HDMI:EDID CEA mode (19) 1280x720p @ 50 Hz with pixel clock 74 MHz has a score of 3738240

HDMI:EDID CEA mode (20) 1920x1080i @ 50 Hz with pixel clock 74 MHz has a score of 3307360

HDMI:EDID CEA mode (21) 1440x576i @ 50 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz has a score of 120736

HDMI:EDID DMT mode (21) 1152x864p @ 75 Hz with pixel clock 108 MHz has a score of 174649

HDMI:EDID CEA mode (31) 1920x1080p @ 50 Hz with pixel clock 148 MHz has a score of 307360

HDMI:EDID DMT mode (35) 1280x1024p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 108 MHz has a score of 178643

HDMI:EDID DMT mode (36) 1280x1024p @ 75 Hz with pixel clock 135 MHz has a score of 98304

HDMI:EDID DMT mode (47) 1440x900p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 106 MHz has a score of 177760

HDMI:EDID DMT mode (48) 1440x900p @ 75 Hz with pixel clock 136 MHz has a score of 197200

HDMI:EDID DMT mode (51) 1600x1200p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 162 MHz has a score of 215200

HDMI:EDID DMT mode (58) 1680x1050p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 146 MHz has a score of 205840

HDMI:EDID preferred mode remained as CEA (2) 720x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz

HDMI:EDID has HDMI support and audio support edid_parser exited with code 0
```

Comment: Is your cable good enough?

Answer (score 5):

I have an old (at least 15 years) Sharp Aquos LC-19A1E TV/monitor and a new 512Mb revision B Raspberry Pi. With original `config.txt`, it came up with a 1080i 60Hz screen. The screen resolution in LXDE said something like 1860x??? (forgot.) It was way above the max resolution described in my TV manual (1366x768).

So it tried editing config.txt:

```
hdmi_group=2
```

and

```
hdmi_mode=81
```

no effect.

Then, I added this command as first line in `config.txt`

```
hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080
```

And voila, it works like a charm. Native resolution and a crisp view on my tv.

Also more about `config.txt` on http://elinux.org/RPiconfig

Comment: `hdmi_ignore_edit=0xa5000080` tells the system to ignore the devices EDID information allowing you to set any DMT or CEA mode you desire.

Answer (score 1):

As @Iamyrus suggests, put `hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080` into your `/boot/config.txt` file.

However, since the [Acer H243HX monitor](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Acer-H243HX-24-inch-Monitor-80000/dp/B002MRRKPW) is native 1920x1080 and since CEA mode 5 is listed when you edit your display's EDID block I would recommend setting the following in your `/boot/config.txt`:

```
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=16
```

You can also test this by just placing `hdmi_ignore_edid` in your config.txt and then executing:

```
/opt/vc/bin/tvservice -m "CEA 16"
```

According to your EDID information CEA 16 is:

```
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 16, 1920x1080p @ 60Hz
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with config_hdmi_boost=4 in config.txt

Comment: Hi Christian, could you try and add a bit more detail?

Comment: He wanted a higher resolution, It seems he have to use the above code according to: http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting (search for config_hdmi_boost).